# Log4j in Grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm trying to create a log file based on methods e.g. `login.log`, `signup.log` using log4j. How should I configure?

This is what i have done and my log file is created but empty. Here is the log4j

```
log4j = {
   appenders {
      rollingFile name:'gsError', file:'Logs/gsError.log', maxSize: 1024
   }
   error gsError:   ['org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',
                     'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
                     'org.springframework',
                     'org.hibernate',
                     'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate']

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

If you read the [documentation on logging](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging), it should be a simple case of creating an appender per file you want to create, then adding this appender to the level declaration (tied to a controller).

All of this is in the `Appenders` section of the logging docs (linked to above)

Have you tried this?